# Uncaught SyntaxError: "Unexpected end of input"

Tags: titanium-mobile

I have reviewed several responses to this matter however I can not find an error in my code.

```
button1.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    pesquisa.open("POST","http://10.0.2.2/jobfinder/teste.php");
    var params = {
        pesquisa: box1.value
    };
    pesquisa.send(params);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vera,

Unexpected end of input error usually means there is a an unclosed parenthesis or bracket.  Please post the full sample of code you are executing and I can find the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
button1.addEventListener('click',function(e) )
{
```

you were missing a closing parenthesis after `function(e)`

Comment: The closing parenthesis is at the end.  });

Comment: This is incorrect as the parenthesis don't need to close until after the function definition, which they do.

Answer (score 0):

On Galaxy S3 with OS 4.1.2 the very same error was thrown (from line 1) when script at the end of file contained line commented with `//` markup, as reported here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23437

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the < SyntaxError > : *Unexpected end of input...* means that the function/code_expression or chunk code ended, while the parser expected that there was more - perhabs unclosed apostrophe (' or inserted mistakenly,eg scale's=*.* instead of scales=*.*), or unclosed bracket ")"  or "}" or *even a mispelt parameter name for a function being used*.

I have used a function, and in the call in another code did not spell rightly one of the parameters, SD=p instead of sd=p used in the function. I got the error message too.